# More destinations for off-topic questions

Tags: feature-request, flagging, scope

Often, I see a question that is off-topic, but I only see options on the flagging interface to flag for a close or to flag to send it to meta, which is quite limited. Is this by design since other sites don't want AU's posts being dumped there, or should this be implemented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is by design and hopefully it will be changed with a better solution.

The moderators need to evaluate the need to migrate to another SE site before the decision is made, no one should want that automated, lets not give more power to the robots in our life.

*Too much automation is evil!*

Comment: Sure, whatever you need. But this has already been discussed a few times here, search box might return similar interesting subjects. Have a look ;)

Comment: @ObsessiveFOSS I vouch for Bruno's opinion. The only people who can migrate are moderators, and we always have to ask the destination site first.